# Narrow-by-list containing wrong item with full page cache

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

On our Magento 1.9.4, we have category pages with 3 product attributes used for the narrow-by-list. E.g. in a "Fashion" category, these lists look like this:

```
Clothe type:
   /fashion/l/shoes
   ...
Color:
   /fashion/l/green
   ...
```

Now, when you click on the `clothe-type=shoes` link, and we also have *green* shoes, then the next page has a `color=green` link combined with the shoes filter of the current url:

```
Color:
   /fashion/l/shoes/green
```

So the product list then is filtered on multiple attributes. That works mostly like a charm here.

Now, on the /fashion page, the link for `color=green` sporadically includes the "shoes" filter although the current url clearly misses that shoes filter:

```
Color:
   /fashion/l/shoes/green
```

Keeping in mind that we also run a full page cache. I suppose this cache drives me crazy but I'm curious if anyone else has seen this?